# Hyplerlink to a file on another drive letter, same server

Tags: php, apache, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a hyper link to a file on the same server, but on a different drive.

Running Apache on my server.  I don't want the hyperlink to start with file:///// because thats not compatible with firefox, and it's just not what I want to do.

It there a way to get this done?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: file:// definitely works in Firefox. The problem is that a file: url points to the LOCAL machine the browser is running on. It doesn't allow you access a file on a remote server.

Comment: file://  might work in firefox, doesn't in chrome. just tested it.

Comment: Works fine here. Remember that file:// is local to YOUR machine, it's not browsing the server's drive. That's your `c:\` or `/` or whatever it'd be on your desktop OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to point a piece of the URL space to the other drive.

Comment: Another approach is using symlinks, and here is a discussion why aliases are better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561441/apache-alias-vs-symbolic-link